# How to display a 2D array in a grid form?

Tags: python

I am trying to learn 2D arrays and how they work, I tried displaying data provided in a grid/table like form, however, it is displaying it by rows and not by column.

The following list of input will show what I mean:

DESIRED INPUT:

````
exList= ["Table1", "Table2", "Table3"], ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"], ["Example1", "Example2", "Example 3"]```
````

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Table1 Test1 Example1
Table2 Test2 Example2
Table3 Test3 Example3
```

My code right now:

```
exList= ["Table1", "Table2", "Table3"], ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"], ["Example1", "Example2", "Example 3"]

for row in range(len(exList)):
   for col in range(len(exList[row])):
      print(exList[row][col], end=" ")
   print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over the lists in parallel

```
ex_list = ["Table1", "Table2", "Table3"], ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"], ["Example1", "Example2", "Example 3"]

for table, test, example in zip(*ex_list):
    print(table, test, example)
```

Output:

```
Table1 Test1 Example1
Table2 Test2 Example2
Table3 Test3 Example 3
```

Comment: is there a diffrent method I can use without zip?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, just change row and col in exList index

```
exList= ["Table1", "Table2", "Table3"], ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"], ["Example1", "Example2", "Example 3"]

for row in range(len(exList)):
   for col in range(len(exList[row])):
      print(exList[col][row], end=" ")
   print()
```